# How to correctly restart Docker containers for deployment process?

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose

I am creating a script that I will use as GitHub webhook after each push to master. Now in this script my deployment looks something like this:

```
cd directory/to/docker-compose
git pull
docker-compose up --build -d --force-recreate
```

So every time I make a push to master, I am suposed to execute a deployment script that pulls changes from GitHub and restarts the Docker container with the changes of a code.

Could someone confirm or give me some tips if this is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your deployment process shouldn't involve Git at all.  The standard way to do this is:

1. Have your CI system run `docker build` to build an image from each commit.  Tag each image with a date stamp, source control tag, source control change ID, or something else (or all of these; but something unique, not `latest`).
2. `docker push` the built images to some central registry (Docker Hub, Amazon ECR, Google GCR, something self-hosted, ...).
3. Change the image tag in the `docker-compose.yml` and re-run `docker-compose up`.  Compose will notice that the image has changed, stop the old container, pull the changed image, and start a new one.

In the last step note that the `image:` tag supports [environment variable expansion](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution), so your `docker-compose.yml` can say something like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  one:
    image: "myorg/service-one:${SERVICE_ONE_TAG:-latest}"
```

which will use `latest` if the environment variable isn't set, but your CI/CD system can set the environment variable to get something different.

(This same approach is critical if you move to Kubernetes: you generally don't have direct login access to nodes so you can't pull source code or assets on to the host; you'd have to do it by hand on *every* host; and a change in the Deployment specification is what keys the system to actually make a change.  If you adopt this setup now, and later move to Kubernetes, you'll get its zero-downtime rolling upgrade system for free.)